# Unable to reorder user properties in SharePoint 2010

Tags: property

for some reason I am unable to change the order of user properties in Central Administration > Manage User properties.

I was able to change the order of some of them until a certain point, but then they would stop moving and wouldn't budge anymore no matter how many times I clicked those little blue arrows.

Also, I am not able to delete some of the user properties either, even though I am using an admin account.

Any idea of what might be causing my issues?